# ACF: Display Fields in a template based on Cpt ui

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I have created a custom post type based on CPT Ui I am tryin to display the items of that in a template ideally what I want to be able to do is

www.siteurl.com/profile/profilename

Hence why I have created a template page with the following code.

But I dont no how I would get profilename into my query posts and then display the relivent data this is what I have tired so far to get id and permalink to display but to no avail.

I really want to be able to do it like how the documentation states. Ideally i would suspect my best approach would be to check if user has created a profile in the front end if not direct them to do so?.

Display a field

```
<p><?php the_field('field_name'); ?></p>
```

http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/code-examples/

```
<?php
/**
 * Template Name: Profile Page
 */

get_header(); ?>
<?php get_template_part( 'page', 'title' ); ?>


<div class="width-container">



    <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
        <?php get_template_part( 'content', 'page' ); ?>
    <?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>

    <?php

$posts = get_posts(array(
    'numberposts' => -1,
    'post_type' => 'profiles',
    'meta_key' => 'profilename',
    'meta_value' => 'david'
));

if($posts)
{
    echo '<ul>';

    foreach($posts as $post)
    {
        echo '<li><a href="' . get_permalink($post->ID) . '">' . get_the_title($post->ID) . '</a></li>';
    }

    echo '</ul>';
}

?>
    <?php get_sidebar(); ?>

</div><!-- close .width-container -->
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

If anyone has done anything simlar maybe I should be using current user but  again i dont no how to link that up to acf as I am new to that plugin

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could try another approach and build a custom query with `WP_Query` instead. The example bellow use the **WP_Query** object rather than the **get_posts** function, however the arguments and logic remain the same.

This implies we will find all posts that have a post_type of `profiles` where the ’custom field’ `profilename` is equal to `david`. The custom field ‘profilename’ in this case could be a text field, a radio button or a select field (something that saves a single text value).

```
<?php
/**
 * Template Name: Profile Page
 */

 get_header();

 $user = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'profilename', true); // saving the field value in a $variable can help to build a more dynamic WP_Query... 

?>

<?php get_template_part( 'page', 'title' ); ?>

<div class="width-container">
 <h1>__('Listing Posts by:', 'text_domain');</h1>
 <?php echo '<p class="text-center">' . esc_html( $user ) . '</p>'?>;

<?php 
// args
$args = array(
 'numberposts'  => -1,
 'post_type'        => 'profiles',
 'meta_key'     => 'profilename',
 'meta_value'   => $user // retrieve the actual profilename field value
);


// query
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

?>
<?php if( $the_query->have_posts() ): ?>
    <ul>
<?php while( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>
    <li>
       <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
         <?php the_title(); ?>
       </a>
    </li>
<?php endwhile; ?>
</ul>

<?php endif; ?>

<?php wp_reset_query();  // Restore global post data stomped by the_post(). ?>

<?php get_sidebar(); ?>

</div><!-- close .width-container -->
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

The code above is an example of how to query ("get and display") posts in WP using WP_Query object within a template based on custom field called ‘profilename’ which has a value of ‘david’ or whatever data is saved inside the field as per your example.

Perhaps you want to display the relevant data (values) of the custom fields you've created for the WP default user profile page, and if this is the case, you should follow another approach and instead of query posts you simply output the fields a user might fill on their profile. In order to that you could [Get values from a user](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/how-to-get-values-from-a-user/).

This example will display the field 'profilename' value from a user with an ID of 1.

`<?php the_field('field_name', 'user_1'); ?>`

Within your loop you could use `$user_ID = get_current_user_id();` to retrieve the user_id as follows:

```
<?php
/**
 * Template Name: Profile Page
 */

 get_header();

 $user = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'profilename', true); // saving the field value in a $variable can help to build a more dynamic WP_Query... 

 $user_ID = get_current_user_id();

?>

<?php get_template_part( 'page', 'title' ); ?>

<div class="width-container">
 <h5>__('Listing Posts by:', 'text_domain');</h5>
 <h1><?php the_field('profilename', '$user_ID'); ?>;</h1> // this will retrieve the data/value saved in the 'profilename' field for the current user

...
```

Check [ACF's Query Posts by Custom Fields](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/query-posts-custom-fields/) documentation for other ways to retrieve an array of post objects from the database using native WP functions.

Comment: thaks for the reply i dont understand meta_key would that be the field i require how do i output the individual fields i require on the profile page

Comment: When you create a field in ACF you have to define the Field Name, it is used to save and load data from the database. This name must be a single word, no spaces, underscores and dashes are allowed. After setting up your fields with unique names there are a few ways to retrieve its data. So in order to output the data of a field named `profilename`, you'd simple put <?php the_field('profilename'); ?> anywhere on your .php templates.

Comment: The meta_key is the field itself which data is the meta_value, they're being used within the $args variable in order to build the WP_Query, but you won't need them on much simpler situations when you intend just to output a fields value.

Comment: The code above shows how to build a custom loop within a template to display all posts assigned to the `profiles` post_type where the `profilename` field is equal to whatever the value inserted in the profilename field is, so let's say the field's value it's `david`, this means all posts which have the `profilename` field with a value of david will be shown.